# sql join issues with different data

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join two tables with different data and data type is same.

In tableA the column col1 is with varchar datatype i.e. 123 and in tableB the column col1 is with varchar datatype i.e. ABC-123

Is there any way to join both columns by adding ABC as prefix to col1 in table 1 or by removing prefix ABC from col1 table 2.

[image]

Comment: Don't do this. Instead normalise your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT()`, as in:

```
select *
from table_a a
join table_b b on concat('ABC-', a.col1) = b.col2
```

This issue is quite common, specially in old databases, where you need to join `VARCHAR` columns with `NUMERIC` ones, since the designers back in the 90s though it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Just use function `CONCAT()` at the `ON` clause of `INNER JOIN`

```
select * from
tableA a inner join tableB b
on CONCAT('ABC-', a.col1) = b.col2
```

Comment: Wow, both answers are within 30s of each other.